# I cannot update the metadata in the intranet site's html in the Azure blob container

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

My chatbot should provide the link of the intranet HTML page which is stored in the blob container.

I want to add a new metadata to the uploaded page, which should have the link address of the intranet path and the user will be redirected to the login page.

Right not when I try this it says lease id is not specified. Anyone know how can I update such HTML pages?

[image: error page screen shot]

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lease on an azure blob is like a lock/hold so that while the lease is present no other application can alter this blob. I believe that currently some application of yours is using the blob and has a lease on it. Only if that lease is cleared you will be able to modify or delete the blob.

if this is a one time issue you can manually remove the lease on the blob programmatically or using [Powershell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-break-the-locked-c2cd6492).

if you are acquiring [lease](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.acquirelease(v=azure.10).aspx) on the blob as a requirement then make sure that you [release](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.releaselease(v=azure.10).aspx) the lease programmatically before making changes to the blob.